# Synonyms check in LaTeX/TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter, dictionaries

I would like to ask that as in Microsoft word it is possible to check synonyms of every word. Is there any same feature available in LaTeX/TeXnicCenter?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think you know this but it does not hurt to mention, LaTeX itself does not have such features, that's more of an editor thing. I haven't used TeXniccenter so I don't know wheter it offers this or not. But what I **do know** is that TeXstudio has it, and it also highlights word repetition.

Comment: TeXniccneter implies Windows, but you might look into [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/) and whether it can be used from the commandline or integrated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (I'm using TeXnicCenter) it has no thesaurus (name of the program that offers synonyms) included into the program.

You can ask on the support page (see homepage of TeXnicCenter) to add an thesaurus to it ...